# Graph of complex exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to graph this set on a complex plane: $$A=\{z\in C :|e^{iz}|\ge|e^z|\}$$

I know that: $$|e^{ix-y}|\ge|e^{x+iy}|$$ $$|e^{-y}e^{ix}|\ge|e^xe^{iy}|$$ $$|e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)|\ge|e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)|$$ $$e^{-y}\ge e^x$$ $$-y\ge x$$

But I'm not sure how to graph it since $e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$ and both $x$ and $y$ are changing. Can you give me any hints? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You are graphing the set $A$, not a function.  $-y = x$ is a line in the $xy$ plane, and $-y \ge x$ is the region on one side of that line.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. So if an exp function transforms a vertical line in a complex plane to a ray, then in this case it would be just an inverse?

I'm referring to this: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-graph-of-the-complex-exponential-function#toc0

Comment: What would be an inverse of what?  I repeat, you are graphing the set $A$.  You already found what that set is.